# How to use an object's value as the parameter for another object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have:

```
var key = "Section";
course.key = "101";
```

I get told `course.key is unidentified`. I'm trying to set `course.Section = "101"`. Is there anyway to pass key's value in the second line?

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `key` of `course` is undefined. Use bracket notation.

`course[key] = "101"`

is the same as

`course["Section"] = "101"`